# Docker installation debian openjdk-7-jre

Tags: docker, debian, java

I've been trying to install openjdk-7-jre in a docker image. But when I tried to install it I got the following error:

> E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u111-2.6.7-2~deb8u1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 200.17.202.197 80]

I've been spending a lot of hours trying this. For More details, the instruction in the Dockerfile is:

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -f xvfb wget 
RUN sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --fix-missing -y -f openjdk-7-jre

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg --unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get install -f -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get update && \
    rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

RUN npm install -g protractor mocha jasmine cucumber && \
    webdriver-manager update && \
    apt-get update
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Is the docker connected to INTERNET?

Comment: yes, in fact, this is the one package that not achieves downloade successfully

Comment: Are you able to get `open jdk` Debian installer on your local machine using `wget` successfully? if so, then you can simply `ADD` or `COPY` into docker build context.

Comment: Is using the official Java image at all an option for this?

Comment: I think that my problem is related to the error part: `Connection failed [IP: 200.17.202.197 80]`, my container isn't expose the port 80. I'll will try exposing this port.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you are getting an error in the second `RUN` command, `apt-get update -qq`. The error is getting buried because of `-qq` flag (which will quite the error messages. Try without `-qq` to diagnoise the error)

[image]

You can try using below `Dockerfile` for installing `openjdk-7-jre`.

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install --fix-missing -y -f openjdk-7-jre
```

Answer (score 1):

just added `FROM debian:jessie` to your `dockerfile` and successfully built the image. Your problem is your `internet connection`, Use `VPN` or `Proxy` servers to build the image.